# Button click to set checkboxes to true in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This question is a bit tricky but anyway here it goes, So I have a gridview with three columns two of them are boolean checkboxes. What I want to do is when a user click on a button in edit/update mode I want to set both boxes to true or 1. So how can I do that? Help would be much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

A sample of my code in edit mode:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="reservationid, bookid, EmployeeID" 
            DataSourceID="bookreservationDataSource">
            <Columns>

                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" 
                    ShowSelectButton="true"/>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="booktitle" HeaderText="Title" 
                    ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="booktitle" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee ID" 
                    ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="EmployeeID" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="reservedate" HeaderText="Reserve date" 
                    SortExpression="reservedate" />

                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="isapproved" HeaderText="Approved" 
                    SortExpression="isapproved" />

                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="isdeleted" HeaderText="Deleted" 
                    SortExpression="isdeleted" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I want to set the two checkbox field 'isapproved' and 'isdeleted' to true when a button like 'edit' is set.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this on the client side or the server side?

Comment: show your code on what have you done. there are so many ways

Comment: @Tim: yes if you could please. I'll add the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like...

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("FirstCheckBox")).Checked = true;
        ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("SecondCheckBox")).Checked = true;
        GridView1.UpdateRow(row.RowIndex,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir if I may ask whats the reference to RowIndex? I have an error: it said it does not contain definition for 'RowIndex'.

Comment: @Loupi; Can you remove this line GridView1.UpdateRow(row.RowIndex,true); and then try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks but it didnt set the two check boxes to true when I click the edit button. Should I make a custom edit button?

Comment: If I provide you code using Javascript, will that work for you ?

Comment: Please do so. Also I fixed some typo and still wouldn't set the two textbox to true.